# Spring Boot validation - one from two not null

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

I'm trying to validate if one of two fields are not null in Spring Boot?

I have set that in the method class for the main object:

```
@NotNull(message = "Username field is required")
private String username;

@NotNull(message = "Email field is required")
private String email;
```

but that will require to have both fields not null. Then I went with custom validation described here https://lmonkiewicz.com/programming/get-noticed-2017/spring-boot-rest-request-validation/ but I wasn't able to get that example to work. I have to stuck on

User class declaration:

```
@CombinedNotNull(fields = {"username","email"})
public class User implements {

    private long id = 0L;
    @NotNull(message = "First name field is required")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "Last name field is required")
    private String lastName;

    private String username;
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Status field is required")
    private String status;

    ...all methods here...
    ...setters and getters...

}
```

CombibnedNotNull class:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = userValidator.class)
public @interface CombinedNotNull {
        String message() default "username or email is required";
        Class<?>[] groups() default { };
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

userValidator class:

```
@Component
public class userValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CombinedNotNull, User> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final CombinedNotNull combinedNotNull) {
        fields = combinedNotNull.fields();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final User user, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final BeanWrapperImpl beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(user);

        for (final String f : fields) {
            final Object fieldValue = beanWrapper.getPropertyValue(f);

            if (fieldValue == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to get this done or should I go with the "complex" example from that page?

Comment: Anyway take a look at my question&answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957854/spring-validation-class-level-validation-to-address-field-errors

Comment: Class validation is the optimal way to go. Which errors are you getting?

Comment: @LppEdd I have updated OP with the errors. It throws that `RUNTIME`, `FIELD`, `ANNOTATION_TYPE`, `PARAMETER` cannot find symbols for them.

Comment: They're static imports. Just qualify them with ElementType or RetentionPolicy (e.g. ElementType.FIELD - RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

Comment: @LppEdd OK, moved forward and it came up I'm not able to pass two fields into `ConstraintValidatorContext`

Comment: What do you mean "pass" two fields? Inside ConstraintValidator#isValid you have access to the entire object and you can check field by field.

Comment: You need a **class** annotation, not a **field** annotation here

Comment: @LppEdd so I'm lost now - all examples which I saw had field annotations

Comment: See my answer, it should be almost what you want.

Comment: @LppEdd Great! Now I need to get it understand for future usage :)

Comment: Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to implement it for you (even if I'm without an IDE).
Inside `ConstraintValidator#initialize` you can get a hold of the configured fields' names which **cannot** be `null`.

```
@Override
public void initialize(final CombinedNotNull combinedNotNull) {
    fields = combinedNotNull.fields();
}
```

Inside `ConstraintValidator#isValid` you can use those fields' names to check the `Object` fields.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    final BeanWrapperImpl beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(value);
    
    for (final String f : fields) {
       final Object fieldValue = beanWrapper.getPropertyValue(f);
       
       if (fieldValue == null) {
          return false;
       }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Annotation:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = CombinedNotNullValidator.class)
public @interface CombinedNotNull {
    String message() default "username or email is required";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * Fields to validate against null.
     */
    String[] fields() default {};
}
```

The annotation could be applied as

```
@CombinedNotNull(fields = {
      "fieldName1",
      "fieldName2"
})
public class MyClassToValidate { ... }
```

To learn how to create a Class-level constraint annotation, refer always to the official documentation. [Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#section-class-level-constraints)

Comment: Somehow for `@CombinedNotNull(fields = { "user","email"})`  `fields`  cannot be resolved

Comment: @JackTheKnife well you need to adjust your annotation. Maybe post the actual code.

Comment: @JackTheKnife see my updated answer. Look that I renamed the validator from "userValidator" to "CombinedNotNullValidator" and added a String array "fields"

Comment: OK. I see what I have missed. Now I need to change little bit `ConstraintValidator#isValid` as I'm looking for `username` OR `email` is not null (one of them must be present)

Comment: @JackTheKnife you can generalize this constraint by **not** hardcoding the fields name

Comment: In ConstraintValidator class, it is unable to find variable fields in which we are assigning the value of fields from combinedNotNull object. @LppEdd do you have any idea how I can resolve it?

Comment: @DeepakAggarwal just define it in the validator class, see my answer for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146713/386201

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming `username` **OR** `email` must not be null. Not **XOR**.

Add this getter in `User` class:

```
@AssertTrue(message = "username or email is required")
private boolean isUsernameOrEmailExists() {
    return username != null || email != null;
}
```

In my experience, the method name must follow the getter name convention otherwise this won't work. For examples, `getFoo` or `isBar`.

This has a small problem: the field name from this validation error would be `usernameOrEmailExists`, only 1 error field. If that is not a concern, this might help.

---

But If you want to have `username` and `email` fields when errors occur, you can use this workaround:

```
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

@AssertTrue(message = "username or email is required")
private boolean isUsername() {
    return isUsernameOrEmailExists();
}

@AssertTrue(message = "username or email is required")
private boolean isEmail() {
    return isUsernameOrEmailExists();
}

private boolean isUsernameOrEmailExists() {
    return username != null || email != null;
}
```

`get...` methods are just simple getters for general use, and `is...`  are for validation. This will emit 2 validation errors with `username` and `email` fields.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to validate that exactly one is set and the others are null:

## Annotation

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = OneNotNullValidator.class)
public @interface OneNotNull {
    String message() default "Exactly one of the fields must be set and the other must be null";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * Fields to validate against null.
     */
    String[] fields() default {};
}
```

## Validator

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class OneNotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OneNotNull, Object> {
    private String[] fields;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final OneNotNull combinedNotNull) {
        fields = combinedNotNull.fields();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object obj, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final BeanWrapperImpl beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(obj);

        return Arrays.stream(fields)
                .map(beanWrapper::getPropertyValue)
                .filter(Objects::isNull)
                .count()
                == 1;
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
@OneNotNull(
    fields = {"username","email"},
    message="Either username or email must be set"
)
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String email;

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi! Why are you using @Component annotation?