# How can we use either of the validation in spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, validation, jpa

I have two variables in my bean and I want either name or mobile to be filled, they cant be both null at the same time.

```
@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull
private String mobile;
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638255/spring-boot-validation-one-from-two-not-null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot validation - one from two not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638255/spring-boot-validation-one-from-two-not-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a custom annotation for this and use on class

```
@AtLeastOneNotEmpty(fields = {"name", "phone"})
public class User{
```

Custom Annotation Implementation

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = AtLeastOneNotEmptyValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AtLeastOneNotEmpty {

  String message() default "At least one cannot be null";

  String[] fields();

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And Validator of Custom Annotation

```
public class AtLeastOneNotEmptyValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<AtLeastOneNotEmpty, Object> {

  private String[] fields;

  public void initialize(AtLeastOneNotEmpty constraintAnnotation) {
    this.fields = constraintAnnotation.fields();
  }

  public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    List<String> fieldValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String field : fields) {
      Object propertyValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(field);
      if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(propertyValue)) {
        fieldValues.add(null);
      } else {
        fieldValues.add(propertyValue.toString());
      }
    }
    return fieldValues.stream().anyMatch(fieldValue -> fieldValue!= null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own validation or annotation
try like this :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotNullConfirmed {
    String message() default "they can not be null";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and class that implement it:

```
   public class FieldConfirmedValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNullConfirmed, Object>{
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object user, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String name = ((Your_bo)user).getName();
        String phone = ((Your_bo)user).getPhone();
        return !name.isEmpty() && !phone.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

and add this annotation to your class

```
@NotNullConfirmed 
public class User{
}
```

Comment: How your validator connected with Annotation and what `Your_bo` here ?