# Different annotation implementation for nested objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a POJO like

```
public genericModel {

   @NotNull
   private int id;

   @NotBlank
   private String category;

   //null for a root genericModel
   //notNull for a child genericModel
   private String modelType;

   private genericModel child;

  //getters and setters respectively
}
```

I want to have validation for modelType such a way that for the child object that field should not be null but for a parent object it should be null. Is there a provision to have this in spring or should I write a custom validator?

Comment: How can you decide which one root and which one child?

Comment: If the object is used in another object it is a child. If not it is a root.

Comment: So it is not possible to check only one object information

Comment: Ideally no. But let's say I keep a flag indicating child or parent. Is it possible to have this type of validation

Comment: Yes possible then you  can write an custom annotation and use it on class. In custom annotation validator you can validate. Here you find an example how to write custom annotation https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303264/4207306

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try and post the solution if I can make it work. Thanks a lot.