# How to use @NotEmpty by combining 2 fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, javax.validation

I have the following request.

```
@Data
public class ProductRequest {
    @NotEmpty
    private String code;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
}
```

I use this request for 2 different methods and both of them use only one field, not need the other field. Let's say that methodA using `code` and methodB using `name` field in this request (not need other field). So, in this scene I think a solution for using the same request for both methods, instead of creating 2 separate request. So, is there anything that make it possible one of the field is not null? I am also not sure if it solves my problem, because in this scene request will not know which property should not be null. Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Can these asnwers help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638255/spring-boot-validation-one-from-two-not-null ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not helped. Any example for my code pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group your constraints so that you can tell which properties to be validated in each case. The first step is to add the attribute `groups` to your *javax* validation annotations. For that you need to create some marker interfaces, one for each of your use cases:

```java
public interface MethodA { } // You should name this properly, it is just for demonstration purposes

public interface MethodB { }
```

Then you need to configure the `groups` attribute in your annotations:

```java
@Data
public class ProductRequest {
    @NotEmpty(groups = MethodA.class)
    private String code;

    @NotEmpty(groups = MethodB.class)
    private String name;
}
```

The final step is the usage of `@Validated` instead of `@Valid` to trigger data validation. Something along the following lines:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/methodA", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String methodA(@Validated(MethodA.class) @RequestBody ProductRequest productRequest) {
    (...)
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/methodB", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String methodB(@Validated(MethodB.class) @RequestBody ProductRequest productRequest) {
    (...)
}
```

You can read more about this in the following online resources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated

Comment: Not tested yet, but seems a proper approach. ON the other hand, I think it may be good idea to use a single property and pass it via `@PathVariable @NotNull String name` instead of using a Request class. Is that true?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do in the POST method and what does that `name` mean. What is your intent?

Comment: I am trying to update name field.

Comment: Then you shouldn't do it you a path variable. Your REST resource is `Product` and you should use a `PATCH` request to update its `name` attribute providing it the request body.

Comment: What about using name parameter in the request? SHould I use Request class for that rather than parameters except from id or uuid?

Comment: Now I am not following you. I would suggest you create a new question with all the details since we are drifting a bit on the topic itself. Add the link here as a comment so that I can check it. Thanks! ;)

Comment: No need to follow, you may just reply my comment

Comment: And as a consequence, you removed my answer which is correct as accepted. I don't think that is the spirit we are looking forward to here at StackOverflow but ok. The question is that I can't reply to your comment because I don't understand what you are trying to ask. There is no `id` or `uuid` in your question, so I don't know what you are talking about. It may make sense to you but it does not to us. And again, changing the scope of a question after it was already correctly answered is not something you should do, otherwise, no question will have an end.

Comment: @Henry, if you want me to help you, I need you to give me more details of what is now your issue. The best way to do this is by creating a new question on which you can describe the problem clearly instead of being restricted by the number of characters of a comment. So please do it and post here the link to the question. I will take a look. Then, accept again my answer so that this question can be "closed" again. Thanks!

Comment: Marked as answer and voted up, thanks a lot for your valuable helps.

Comment: What about my other question on the other thread?

Comment: I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do it with a [custom validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validator) (spring, code validation, no javax.)
2. With javax.validation:

   - [Groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups) sound like a perfect match for your scenario.
   - of course also achievable with a [Custom Constraint](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints). (similar to 1.)

   Drawback: you'll have to deal with your "validation structure" ([`@Valid` vs `@validated`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated)/how to pass the `group`)
3. ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I have a look at these pages, but I am not sure if they exactly help me for my situation. Because, as you know, my request should also need to know which field should be not null. So, if you think it is possible, could you pls post an example implementation for this request above as an update to your answer?

Comment: By the way I could not see a proper example r definition for  javax.validation Group on the page you referred.